# Android - Couchbase attachments storage and selective pull replication

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, ektorp

I had the following 2 questions on couchbase on android:

- When the couchdb is replicated to the android device, are the attachments in the document downloaded and saved to the SDCard or only the plain document(json) is saved?
- is it possible to perform selective replication. Basically if a couchdb contains a chunk of documents, Can I replicate only a subset of the documents? I am using the Ektorp Client library.

**Update** : For the second question the answer by "[I dropped out of a java school](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357107/500865)" is good. The right term is Filtered Replication.

I'm looking for an answer for the first question with evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachments are fully transferred during replication

You can filter the replication based on the contents of the document with a filter function, you can find more info - http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication

You cannot replication 'parts' of a document, its all or nothing with the replicator

Comment: Can you give me an evidence to prove that "Attachments are full transferred". Thanks for the info on filtered replication.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by evidence, that is just how CouchDB works

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB's concept of replication includes the document, all revisions and all attachments for that document; the replicator makes document A look the same on System 1 as it does on System 2.

In short, your documents and their attachments will go from Android device to server and from server to Android device.